# jQuery - correct way to check for null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some clarification about jQuery coding.

I need to pass my value via ajax to a controller, and I need not need to pass null, because in the marital status column I have a condition where if marital status is married we must pass the anniversary date or else pass 0.

Please confirm whether this is correct coding

```
var AnniversaryDate = $("#IDAnniversaryDate").val() == null ? '0' : $("#IDAnniversaryDate").val()
```

Comment: could be written as `var anniversaryDate = $('#IDAnniversaryDate').val() || 0;`

Comment: The best way to check it's "correct" would be to test it and see if it does what you want or not, in all possible situations. Did you try that? But I'd point out that a) `.val()` may return an empty string rather than `null`, so you need to check for that as well, and b) `0` is a number not a string, so don't put it in quote marks.

Comment: `val()` can also return `undefined` if the jQuery object is empty. I'd suggest coalescing the value as @Dementic suggests, as it's the quickest, easiest and most reliable way to achieve what you need in this case. The only caveat is if you ever expect the value to be `'false'` as a string, but given you're using a date here it would appear to not be an issue.

Comment: @Dementic Thanks for helping, but can this code satisfy the if condition, my condition is ( if marital status is given yes the anniversary date should come or else it should hide), if by hiding the date it is passing null value, but in Stored Procedure null value is not accepting, and _context null error is occurring, please help me in this case

Comment: @mageshkumar you said _"can this code satisfy the if condition"_ ....why not test it for yourself and find out if it works for you or not? If you have a sufficient set of test cases you can verify it easily without waiting for us to do it for you.

Comment: @Dementic ADyson Thank you, i tried the code,but still it's not working the same null error is occurring in the "_Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC [dbo].[Proc_PersonalInfoXml] (@PersonalInfo)", empxml);" area, all the values are coming under there respective fields, but still i am facing the null error, can you please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: i would guess you have an issue on the backend, could you share the code that calls `ExecuteSqlCommand`

Comment: Thanks @Dementic ADyson for helping, issue has been resolved, after this task i need to generate automatic id from front end, for that i am using identity function, but in the if statement false value is passing, i will attach my code in this content, could you please help me to fix this issue ,

Comment: try
            {

                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    //return View(model);

                    var user = new ApplicationUser
                    {
                        UserName = model.UserName,
                        Email = model.Email,
                        PhoneNumber = model.UserId,
                    };

Comment: _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.PasswordHash);
                    //var SignIn = await _signInManager.SignInManager(user,false);
                    ApplicationUser App = await

Comment: _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
  if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
                        
                        _logger.LogInformation(3, "User created a new account with password.");
                        _AdminServices.Procedural(model);

                        return LocalRedirect("model");
                    }

Answer (score 0):

you can use parseInt to get numeric value of date otherwise return 0, see below line of code

```
var AnniversaryDate = parseInt($("#IDAnniversaryDate").val(), 10) || 0;
```